# Getting wikipedia article summary

Tags: php, xml

I have this php function to get the summary from wikipedia

```
$function getWikiData()
{
$keyword = $_GET['q'];
 //initiate 
$ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=opensearch&search=$keyword&format=xml&limit=1");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "myCustomBot");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
            $getData = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
}
            //this output is sent to the template
            $TMPL['getData'] = $getData;
```

The output is as expected an image, title, first paragraph but instead of the image is just a rectangle with a corrupted image icon, and the title with the paragraph are stucked together.
What am i doing wrong? will it need to be styled if so how will i style the xml?

Comment: As blue112 suggests, the result is XML, not HTML.  You can process that in many different ways - PHP provides loads of mechanisms (http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), of which XSLT is one.  I find SimpleXml is very handy for this kind of thing:  http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This API will return you an XML, so you can't just use it as HTML data (even if it's compatible, in theory).

You'll need to transform your XML to be printable as HTML. To do so, you can use XSLT.

For instance :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  xmlns:php="http://php.net/xsl" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="//Image">
        Image source : <xsl:value-of select="@source"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Then you can use `XSLTProcessor` and `DOMDocument` to process it.

Comment: Thank you, got it working. I can't yet to upvote but i set it as answered. Thanks again.